# Custom cfg target in cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
rustc --cfg foo
```

How would I do this in cargo? Is this what `features` are for?

Features seem as if they are only for optional dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#rules :

> When a feature is selected, Cargo will call rustc with --cfg feature="${feature_name}". If a feature group is included, it and all of its individual features will be included. This can be tested in code via #[cfg(feature = "foo")]

Comment: What if you don't want to use a feature, because it's an internal implementation detail, like enabling certain mocks when running tests?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `cfg` flags with cargo like this:

```
cargo build --config 'build.rustflags=["--cfg", "foo"]'
```

But note that this will cause cargo to recompile all the dependencies because it doesn't know which crate this cfg affects.